# getting too many characters in character literal in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting "too many characters in character literal" error. I just want to concatenate some strings but I don't know why this code gives error. I don't have much knowledge in javascript(Jquery). Am I doing something wrong?

I want to concatenate variable("value") to this string.

```
var value = ....;

$('#myuserpageId').attr('action', '<s:url action="saveUser" />?ref=<%=' + value +'%>&pageInfo=<%=........
```

Comment: what is the value ......?

Comment: From some quick research it looks like that error is related to C#/ASP when you use single quotes where double quotes should be used. So we need to see the value or at least the entire string to find out which is the wrong part to fix.

Comment: @hellzone consider using a templating engine. Also, this is an ASP.NET error not a JS error. Please retag the question correctly.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I am not using ASP.NET I am using java(jsp). I think this error is related to my IDE.

Comment: Why do you have a code-block <%= %> there? JSP as well as ASP.Net will consider everyting in the code block to be server side code, not javascript.